# Macbook Pro Core 2 Duo won't install 64-bit OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, 64-bit

I am trying to install OS X 10.7 x64 on my Intel Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro from 2007. Before I was running OS X 10.6.8 x64 which worked fine, but I can't seem to install 10.7 as 64-bit. Somehow it assumes under the installation that it must be x86, since I am not asked which version I want to install.

Apple states that it should be able to run 64-bit (and since Snow Leopard was x64 I don't doubt it).

I have checked for any firmware updates, but all seems to be up to date.

How can I get my machine to install the x64 version? Is there some way to force it?

Comment: what error do you get  ?

Comment: I don't get any error as such. It just installs the OS as x86.

Comment: Then, why do you say it doesn't install the 64 bits version ? Where do you get this statement?

Comment: "uname -a" states "root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_I386 i386", which indicates a 32-bit Kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MacBook Pro has indeed a 64 bits processor but it has a 32 bits EFI. So without a hack you won't be able to boot the 64 bits kernel. ([source](http://www.everymac.com/mac-answers/snow-leopard-mac-os-x-faq/mac-os-x-snow-leopard-64-bit-macs-64-bit-efi-boot-in-64-bit-mode.html))

Comment: Do you know of such a hack?  The OP has asked a follow-up question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103054/getting-osx-to-install-in-64bit-mode-when-unsupported-by-apple