# Unsupported hack or workaround to get 64-bit OS X to install on a MacBook Pro having only 32-bit EFI?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, efi, 64-bit

I want to install the 64-bit OS X 10.7 on my MacbookPro 2,1, which has a 64-bit processor, but only 32-bit EFI and Kernel Boot mode.

I know that this is not officially supported, but I [assume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103049) there is some workaround since the hardware provides everything needed to run a 64-bit OS, except for the EFI.

"Select Startup Mode" tells me, that: *"While your Mac is technically able to run a 64-bit kernel, this is not currently enabled by Apple."*

How can I get that to work? Is there an unsupported hack or workaround?

Comment: Just so that everyone is on the same page - a 64 bit kernel isn't the same as a 64 bit processor: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3773 and http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3770

Comment: I have booted 64 bit OS X 10.6.8 on a 32 bit EFI Core 2 duo iMac, by using GRUB, which I installed alongside debian. Graphics were an issue but it DID work. Maybe with the 10.6.2 64 bit GMA 950 kext, it would work better.

Comment: How did you install 64-bit Mac OS X 10.6.8 on a 32-bit EFI Mac? Did you use another machine to install and transferred the drive?

Answer (score 4):

I found a post on the subject from the guy who wrote [this book about Mac OS X internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321278542).  His post mentions Snow Leopard (10.6), but the issues would be similar for 10.7. See [Mac OS X Internals - Is Your Machine Good Enough for Snow Leopard K64?](https://web.archive.org/web/20200602233051/http://osxbook.com/blog/2009/08/31/is-your-machine-good-enough-for-snow-leopard-k64/)

Here's the part I found most relevant to your question:

> [...] Unfortunately, a 64-bit processor alone doesn’t suffice. Out of the
> box, boot.efi will not boot K64 even if you have a 64-bit processor
> and explicitly request K64 if at least one of the following is true.
>
> 1. The machine has 32-bit EFI.
> 2. The machine’s model is prohibited from booting K64 through a hardcoded list within the boot loader. (A cursory look suggests that
>    the list excludes "non-Pro" machines.)
>
> Both of these "limitations" are technically artificial, albeit to
> different degrees.
>
> The first limitation actually does have merit and is arguably not all
> that artificial. **Although a 32-bit EFI could launch a 64-bit kernel,
> the kernel, when running, would not be able to use firmware services.** *[emphasis mine]* 
> In particular, you wouldn’t have NVRAM. For kernel developers merely
> wanting to run a 64-bit kernel for testing and debugging, this may not
> be an issue [...]

On the one hand, the author states that the limitations may be artificial, which still indicates some promise of a workaround, but on the other hand, as @Koen van Rhee's answer also already pointed out, you may end up with devices without support under 64-bit.

(Aside: Why *do* you want to run the 64-bit kernel, anyway? The [OS X 32-bit kernel *can* run 64-bit programs](https://superuser.com/questions/340549/how-does-osx-run-64bit-binaries-while-running-on-a-32bit-kernel).)

I did some more digging searching for a real workaround of some kind, not just theory.  I found the following: [OS X Daily - Got an Older Mac? MLPostFactor Installs OS X 10.8.3 on Old Unsupported Macs](https://osxdaily.com/2013/04/20/mlpostfactor-installs-os-x-mountain-lion-old-unsupported-macs/).  OS X Daily's article links to a series of forum posts at [MacRumors - [Guide] Success! Install 10.8 on old unsupported Mac](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1325709).  It is a *very* long thread.

I still don't definitively know if you can get the OS X 10.7 64-bit kernel running on *your* specific kind of Mac, but I suspect for the reasons mentioned [in this image](https://web.archive.org/web/20180408070809/http://postimg.org:80/image/tnh0j2qaf/) from the MacRumors forum thread that you can't: *"Problem is cards like [...] Does NOT have 64-bit Kexts [...] 64-Bit Kernel will NOT load these 32-bit kexts"*.  Essentially, what @Koen van Rhee already said.

But then I found [this](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/280675-partial-fix-intel-gma950-for-os-x-108/). Quoting: *"Apple has included 64-bit drivers for GMA950 in the OS X 10.6.2 update. These drivers can be used to provide partial support for GMA950 under OS 10.8."*  ... and I'm thinking: maybe such kexts exist for your card and might work on 10.7 too, if they'd work on 10.6 & 10.8? You may have to hunt and mix & match bits from elsewhere.

To sum up:  I don't believe there to be a single or simple workaround for your desired OS version and hardware version.  If you want to proceed, everything I've read indicates it may be possible (to some degree — accept there may be missing drivers and so missing functionality and/or poor performance), but your work will be cut out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your in depth reply. I'll continue searching and let you know the outcome.

Comment: What about when not using the EFI at all? It's possible to install 64-bit Linux on 64-bit CPU / 32-bit EFI Macs by removing the EFI from the ISO image and causing the 64-bit legacy BIOS bootloader to kick in. https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/ So what about Mac OS X, can it boot in legacy mode?

Answer (score 2):

I could see how there would be a possibility to work around this. I assume this would come from the hackintosh community.

However.. You might be able to run a barebones version of the OS but then run into trouble with drivers. An example would be the graphics card. It's a GMA 950 right? As far as I know Apple never released 64bit drivers for it. So even if you get this running, you would still have only basic video without acceleration.

Reference: http://netkas.org/?p=189